# Netty load balancer in channels pool

Tags: netty

I'm using [protobuf-rpc-pro](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-rpc-pro) for my app  (two systems integration). protobuf-rpc-pro is based on Netty and uses this dependency of Netty:
 <dependency>
     <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
     <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.0.CR1</version>
 </dependency>

I need to implement channels pool for communication between two systems to get high performance. I.e. in my implementation I want to get multiple connections which will send messages in parallel (non-blocking communication). Question here is how can I check if send buffer is full already and switch to another connection (like load balancing). Is there any mechanism for that in Netty or some external implementation? 
Haven't found anything on the Web...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the `Channel#isWritable()` method? As far as I understand, that will return false if the write buffer is too full.

EDIT: Added a simple demonstration of using Channel#isWritebale() together with highWaterMark/lowWaterMark.

```
static InetSocketAddress ADDRESS = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 4711);

static ChannelPipeline createPipeline() {

    ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(100,
            Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
    pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

    pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    return pipeline;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    int suspendedWrites = 0;
    int N = 1000;
    final CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch(N);

    ConnectionlessBootstrap server = new ConnectionlessBootstrap(
            new NioDatagramChannelFactory());
    server.setPipeline(createPipeline());
    server.getPipeline().addLast("printer",
            new SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler() {
                @Override
                public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                        MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println((String) e.getMessage());
                    ready.countDown();
                }
            });
    server.bind(ADDRESS);

    ClientBootstrap client = new ClientBootstrap(
            new NioDatagramChannelFactory());
    client.setPipeline(createPipeline());
    Channel clientChannel = client.connect(ADDRESS).sync().getChannel();

    NioDatagramChannelConfig config = (NioDatagramChannelConfig) clientChannel
            .getConfig();

    config.setWriteBufferLowWaterMark(500);
    config.setWriteBufferHighWaterMark(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        String message = "Hello number " + (i + 1) + " from client\n";
        if (clientChannel.isWritable())
            clientChannel.write(message);
        else {
            clientChannel.write(message).await();
            ++suspendedWrites;
        }
    }

    ready.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.releaseExternalResources();
    client.shutdown();
    server.releaseExternalResources();
    server.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Suspended writes: " + suspendedWrites);
    System.out.println("Missed reads: " + ready.getCount());
}
```

Runing this will show that the Channel#isWriteable() is dependent on the current write buffer size and the values for high and low water marks.

A more elaborated implementation could monitor the changes in interest ops and make the writable channels available on that basis.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I tried to reduce buffer sizes. And I have 1000 threads which perform requests. Request message size is bigger than buffer size. It sounds like it puts all requests in some queue and it sends all these messages for a long time. And during this sending time, isWritable flag is always true.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some setting?

Comment: Your sample looks great! I'll try it.

Comment: In my case I had too big values for WriteBufferLowWaterMark and WriteBufferHighWaterMark settings. Now it works fine. Thank you.